# Passing structures or class objects

Tags: c++

```
struct anup1 {
    int a;
};
void structpass_1(struct anup1 b) // accepting structure
{
    cout << b.a;
};
void structpass_2(struct anup1& b) // accepting address of a structure
{
    cout << b.a;
};

int main() {
    struct anup1 a2;
    a2.a = 100;
    structpass_1(a2);
    structpass_2(a2);
}
```

The above code gives same output...whether accepting parameter is struct / address of struct.

Can anyone please explain to me this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: what did you **expect** that was different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `structpass_1` your structure `anup1` is passed *by value*, so a local copy is done and passed to the function.

Instead, in `structpass_2` the structure is passed `by reference`, i.e. a pointer to the structure instance is passed to the function (you have pointer semantic but value syntax). No local copy of the whole structure is done.

Note that for a simple structure containing only one integer passing by value or by reference is the same from a performance perspective. But when you have more complex (and bigger) data, passing by reference is more efficient.

An important difference between the two cases of passing by value vs. passing by reference is that if you *modify* the structure instance inside the function body, only if the structure is passed by reference the modifications are persistent at the call site. Instead, when you pass the structure by value, since a local copy is done inside the function body, the modifications are lost when the function exits. e.g.:

```
void structpass_1(anup1 b) // pass by value
{
    cout << b.a << '\n';
    b.a++; // modification lost at the call site
};

void structpass_2(anup1& b) // pass by reference
{
    cout << b.a << '\n';
    b.a++; // the caller will see the incremented value for b.a
};

int main() 
{
    anup1 a2;
    a2.a = 100;
    structpass_1(a2); // will print 100
    structpass_2(a2); // will print 100
    cout << a2.a; // willl print 101 (structure modified by structpass_2)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It passes a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29) to struct anup1 to the function.

```
void structpass_2( struct anup1 &b)
```

Have a look about what is reference: [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29)

Also keyword `struct` is not necessary in function parameter list, you can write:

```
void structpass_1(anup1 b) // accepting structure
void structpass_2(const anup1& b) // accepting address of a structure
```

Add `const` qulifier to parameter if it's readonly

Comment: Thanks all!       I was missing the following concept. For C programming language..to pass as reference we need to pass the address of the variables...But in C++ we have "Reference variables" which are declared as int &ref = a; So in the above example I was passing just variable in first case and a "reference variable" in second case....Anyways thanks for your guidance and time..I really appreciate..

Answer (score 2):

```
void structpass_2( struct anup1 &b)
```

This is taking a *reference*.  A pointer would be with a `*`.

Comment: Thanks all!       I was missing the following concept. For C programming language..to pass as reference we need to pass the address of the variables...But in C++ we have "Reference variables" which are declared as int &ref = a; So in the above example I was passing just variable in first case and a "reference variable" in second case....Anyways thanks for your guidance and time..I really appreciate..

Answer (score 1):

The second function

```
void structpass_2( struct anup1 &b)
```

in C++ syntax is pass by reference, pass by reference will simply pass the address of the object into the function.

While the first function

```
void structpass_1(struct anup1 b)
```

uses pass by value. It will first make a copy of struct a, then pass to the function. Pass by reference is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks all!       I was missing the following concept. For C programming language..to pass as reference we need to pass the address of the variables...But in C++ we have "Reference variables" which are declared as int &ref = a; So in the above example I was passing just variable in first case and a "reference variable" in second case....Anyways thanks for your guidance and time..I really appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

These functions are equivalent for a programmer, the only difference they make is in the underlying machine code - the first one operates on a copy (an object), the second one operates on the original object via a reference (so really a pointer).

The output you get is 100% correct.

Comment: Thanks all!       I was missing the following concept. For C programming language..to pass as reference we need to pass the address of the variables...But in C++ we have "Reference variables" which are declared as int &ref = a; So in the above example I was passing just variable in first case and a "reference variable" in second case....Anyways thanks for your guidance and time..I really appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the first one creates an **exact copy** of the object. This is useful for **optimizing** code but remember to use **const** if you do not want to modify the original object.

Comment: Thanks all!       I was missing the following concept. For C programming language..to pass as reference we need to pass the address of the variables...But in C++ we have "Reference variables" which are declared as int &ref = a; So in the above example I was passing just variable in first case and a "reference variable" in second case....Anyways thanks for your guidance and time..I really appreciate..